# Multithreading vs Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, multiprocessing

I currently have a button triggering this:

```
def spam(self,event):
        t = workingthread()
        t.start()
```

Which goes to this:

```
class workingthread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        def run(self):
               while 1:
                       chat = skype.CreateChatWith(name)
                       chat.SendMessage(message)
                       time.sleep(timeou)
```

I'm trying to have this be toggled but I've heard there's no way to stop threads and I don't really want to use multiprocessing. Any other ways i could get this to work without lagging the wx gui?

Comment: Is that a formatting error or is run() really being defined in __init__() ?

Comment: Formatting error. I didn't mean to do that lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this, which I have done myself.

```
from Queue import Queue
import threading

class workingthread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._queue = Queue()

    def run(self):
        while True:

            item = self._queue.get(block=True)
            if item is None:
                return

            name, message = item
            chat = skype.CreateChatWith(name)
            chat.SendMessage(message)

    def processOne(self, data):
        self._queue.put_nowait(data)

    def stop(self):
        self._queue.put(None)
```

This is a rough example obviously, but you create a queue that blocks in the thread. You start the thread whenever you want and it runs. It waits for you to trigger it or stop it.

Comment: Sure. What happens is that your thread starts and goes into the same while loop you had, but instead of constantly spinning forever, it is checking a queue. A queue is like a fancy list that is safe for threads and can block if there is nothing in it. So right away it just sits there at self._queue.get(), waiting for an item. From your main program you can signal it to do something by calling processOne() with your data. It will be placed into the queue and the thread will unblock and process it and then loop and wait again. If you call stop() it will place a None in the queue which will exit

Comment: Why is data needed here     def processOne(self, data):
            self._queue.put_nowait(data)

Comment: Well right now it seems like you are creating all these global variables and using them all over your script. The thread should not have access to global variables like that. It should be passed in the data that it wants to work with. In this example I was suggesting that you pass in the values you want to do a chat message with instead of relying on globals. Honestly I don't know the details of what you really want your script to do.

Comment: Lets continue this in a chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7261/multithreading-vs-multiprocessing

Answer (score 3):

Instead of "while 1", why not substitute some variable that starts "true", and you can change to "false" (signalling the thread to exit).

This assumes, of course, that you're continually looping (and not blocked in a "chat.*" method, or waiting in a "sleep()").

Comment: Exactly. You can't stop child threads yourself, but you can signal them, and they can exit and stop on their own.